# Proof that EXPTIME is well founded

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

I was toying around with the idea of complexity classes and I realized I don't know of a decision problem, off the top of my head that rigorously requires exponential time to solve.

What would be an example of such a problem and a proof of its hardness?

Comment: Isn't the traveling salesman problem exponential?

Comment: the decision version, which has an answer of either YES/NO, to the question "is there a path through all the cities of length less than L" is NP-complete, so its not known to be outside of P. But even the harder version; of finding the optimal path itself (which is what I assume you mean), is only known to NP Hard, but is definitely in P if P=NP, so it wouldn't be an example of a problem currently known to definitely take exponential time to solve

Comment: Ah ok.  That's one giant IF... I don't know anyone who believes $P=NP$.

Comment: true, and I certainly don't, but still its an important question to ask, because I would like to be able to name some hard problems that don't hinge on an open problem to decide whether they are hard :)

Comment: also still if $P \ne NP$ it might be that $NP \subseteq DTIME(n^{\log(n)^{O(1)}}) $ and so again the travelling salesman isn't in $EXPTIME$ as we would've hoped

Comment: If I recall correctly, EXPTIME-complete problems include "concise" versions of the P-complete problems, such as circuit evaluation, where instead of getting (for instance) the circuit as a graph, the input is a function to generate a circuit (obviously in a highly restricted language, or else it would be re-complete).  It's been too long for me to remember the exact definition, though.

Comment: @user361424 yea this is what I saw too, but (perhaps my choice of literature was simply poor) I didn't see any reason why the compressed circuit, doesn't have an efficient way, perhaps unique to compressed circuits, for deciding the property in question.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Look up the Time Hierarchy Theorem, which will explain how it's known the boundary between P and EXPTIME is hard, and the proof will suggest a (very, very artificial) complete problem for the latter class.

Answer (score 1):

A [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition) is a certain type of expression that represents a set of strings.  See the Wikipedia article for the details of regular expressions.

The regular expression non-universality problem is as follows:

> Given a regular expression $R$ over some alphabet $\Sigma$, does there exist a string $s\in\Sigma^*$ for which $s\notin R$?

This is known to be PSPACE-complete, so there is a polynomial-time algorithm if $P=PSPACE$.

To the usual regular expression operations of union, concatenation, and Kleene closure, we will add a new operation: squaring.    If $R$ is any regular expression, let $R^2$ be an abbreviation for $RR$.  Note that this allows us to write very short abbreviations for certain very long expressions.   For example $RRRR…R$ with 65536 $R$s can be abbreviated to $(((…((R^2)^2)…)))$ with only 16 nested applications of $\bullet^2$.

The non-universality problem for this extended notion of regular expressions is provably intractable, requiring exponential time in the worst case, even if $P=PSPACE$.

For the proof, see: Arto Salomaa ''Computation and Automata'', Cambridge University Press, 1985 p.177–179, and the surrounding section 6.5 “Provably Intractable Problems”.  There is also a brief discussion in Garey and Johnson, with a reference.  But the basic idea is that a short input involving several squarings might require us to decide the corresponding problem for an exponentially-larger instance of the problem for basic regular expressions.